# How do you solve this VirtualEnv Running on Jython Error?

Tags: python, virtualenv, jython

I am able to successfully run virtualenv on python, not but on jython (version 2.5.2). What could be the problem and how do I fix this?

Below is the error:

```
Susans-MacBook-Pro:Intro_Jython susantan$ virtualenv -p jython susan_env_jy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/susantan/jython2.5.2/bin/jython
ERROR: None
ERROR: this script requires Python 2.6 or greater.
Susans-MacBook-Pro:Intro_Jython susantan$ virtualenv -p python susan_env_jy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python
New python executable in susan_env_jy/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Jython website:

> The most current stable release of Jython is 2.5.3. For production purposes, please use this version.

From your error message:

> ERROR: this script requires Python 2.6 or greater.

This is probably the cause of the problem. Jython has a 2.7beta1 which you could try.

---

Edit: from the [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) website, it looks like they dropped support for Python 2.5 in v1.10:

> 1.10 (2013-07-23) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> - **BACKWARDS INCOMPATIBLE** Dropped support for Python 2.5. The minimum

You will have to install an earlier version of virtualenv to support Jython 2.5.x

Here is a link to the previous version (1.9.1) https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz - You should be able to install this by extracting the package and running `jython setup.py install` from within the folder.

Comment: Thanks, I now have virtualenv 1.9.1 installed system-wide and the system-wide Jython 2.5.2 is now running inside its own virtualenv. The only potential problem is that this older version of virtualenv is installed system-wide.

Comment: @SusanTan no problem. Please mark this as the accepted answer if your problem has been resolved. Regarding the system wide install, did you install it using `jython setup.py install` as suggested?

Comment: Yes, I used `jython setup.py install`.

Comment: @SusanTan then you possibly still have both versions installed, on my system I have the system wide virtualenv in `/opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7` and the Jython one under the java folder `/opt/local/share/java/jython/bin/virtualenv-2.5` (using Macports on OS X)